# R dplyr to Conditionally Aggregate Based on Group and Column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with subject ID's where I'm taking hourly measurements based on different criteria ("metrics"). Each of these metrics either does or does not meet compliance (1 for yes, 0 for no). I have two goals:

**Tasks**

(1) Determine "full compliance" i.e. a subject has 1's for every metric for every hour. If there is a zero, the subject fails to meet "full compliance".

(2) Determine the percentage of compliance for each subject. I.e. if a subject has 3/4 hours of all 1's then they are 75% compliant.

I would like to solve this using `dplyr` and combinations of `filter()` or some aggregate function I may not be familiar with.

**Example**

Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  "Subject ID" = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  "Metric 1" = rep("value", 12),
  "Compliance 1" = rep(1, 12),
  "Metric 2" = rep("value", 12),
  "Compliance 2" = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1),
  "Metric 3" = rep("value", 12),
  "Compliance 3" = c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
)
```

And here is what I would like to use `dplyr` to achieve for point (1):

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  "Subject ID" = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  "Metric 1" = rep("value", 8),
  "Compliance 1" = rep(1, 8),
  "Metric 2" = rep("value", 8),
  "Compliance 2" = rep(1, 8),
  "Metric 3" = rep("value", 8),
  "Compliance 3" = rep(1, 8)
)
```

For (2) I would like to aggregate the data in a way to show that Subject (A) had 100% compliance but (B) had 50% compliance.

**Edited Answer**

Thanks to tmfmnk I was able to get to the condensed percentages using:

```
df %>%
  mutate(cond = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("Compliance"))) == 1) %>%
  group_by(Subject.ID) %>% 
  tally(cond) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n/4)

  Subject.ID     n  perc
  <fct>      <int> <dbl>
1 A              4   1  
2 B              2   0.5
3 C              4   1
```

Comment: In the data provided, "B" has 2 zeroes and 10 1's. How is that 50% compliant?

Comment: @markhogue Since the zeroes happen in 2 different rows (2 different time points in my real dataset) then B had 2/4 measurements that did not meet compliance.

Comment: Like Mark says, your '50%' compliant statement does not add up. Would Subject B not be 83.3% compliant (10 ones out of 12 possibilities) or 33.3% compliant (1 column of 3 is fully compliant)?

Comment: @kstew No, the check is that all 3 Compliances need to be 1's for the row to be considered compliant. Since two of these rows out of the 4 fail (Observations 5 and 6, though Subject B encompasses observations 5-8), Subject B is only 50% compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a bit lengthy, but the logic should be easy enough to follow -- sum the 1's per compliance column, calculate the compliance percentage, remove subjects with <100% compliance on the 3 compliance columns. Then filter out those subjects from the original dataframe.

```r
compliant <- df %>% select(Subject.ID,matches('Compliance')) %>% 
  gather(k,v,-Subject.ID) %>% 
  group_by(Subject.ID,k) %>% 
  summarise(sum=sum(v),n=n()) %>% 
  group_by(Subject.ID,k) %>%
  mutate(perc=sum/sum(n)) %>% 
  group_by(Subject.ID) %>% summarise(c=sum(perc)) %>% 
  filter(c==3)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Subject.ID     c
  <fct>      <dbl>
1 A              3
2 C              3

df %>% filter(Subject.ID %in% compliant$Subject.ID)

  Subject.ID Metric.1 Compliance.1 Metric.2 Compliance.2 Metric.3 Compliance.3
1          A    value            1    value            1    value            1
2          A    value            1    value            1    value            1
3          A    value            1    value            1    value            1
4          A    value            1    value            1    value            1
5          C    value            1    value            1    value            1
6          C    value            1    value            1    value            1
7          C    value            1    value            1    value            1
8          C    value            1    value            1    value            1
```

Comment: This works wonderfully since I can get the percentages as well. Had not used `gather` before so really appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cond = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("Compliance"))) == 1) %>%
 group_by(Subject.ID) %>%
 filter(all(cond)) %>%
 select(-cond)

      Subject.ID Metric.1 Compliance.1 Metric.2 Compliance.2 Metric.3 Compliance.3
    1          A    value            1    value            1    value            1
    2          A    value            1    value            1    value            1
    3          A    value            1    value            1    value            1
    4          A    value            1    value            1    value            1
    5          C    value            1    value            1    value            1
    6          C    value            1    value            1    value            1
    7          C    value            1    value            1    value            1
    8          C    value            1    value            1    value            1
```

If you want the percentage, then you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(cond = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("Compliance")))) 

   Subject.ID Metric.1 Compliance.1 Metric.2 Compliance.2 Metric.3 Compliance.3      cond
1           A    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
2           A    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
3           A    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
4           A    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
5           B    value            1    value            1    value            0 0.6666667
6           B    value            1    value            0    value            1 0.6666667
7           B    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
8           B    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
9           C    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
10          C    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
11          C    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
12          C    value            1    value            1    value            1 1.0000000
```

To get a percentage of cases fulfilling the condition per group (as proposed by @rsh52):

```
df %>%
 mutate(cond = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("Compliance"))) == 1) %>%
 group_by(Subject.ID) %>% 
 tally(cond) %>% 
 mutate(perc = n/4)

  Subject.ID     n  perc
  <fct>      <int> <dbl>
1 A              4   1  
2 B              2   0.5
3 C              4   1
```

Comment: Wish I could give both you and @kstew credit, this works perfectly as well and is very succinct at solving (1), I'm marking the other post as the answer since it also hits (2). Regardless thank you this helped considerably!

Comment: this is close now. The only issue being that the percentage isn't applied to each row, overall full compliance for the row is still binary. The overall compliance for subject B would be 50% since 2 of the observations fail to have all compliance values of 1.

Comment: I was able to get it now as an edit to what you've made. I'll include in the edit above but would like to leave this here as well in case others have a need for this answer.

Comment: Glad you solved it, I was not sure what exactly are you looking for :)